# How to to filter by media subtype using NSPredicate with PHFetchOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate, photosframework

How do I filter by media subtype using `NSPredicate` with `PHFetchOptions`?
I'm trying to exclude slow mo (high frame rate) and time lapse videos. I keep getting strange results when I try to use the `predicate` field of `PHFetchOptions`.

My phone has a bunch (120+) regular videos, and one slow mo video. When I run the example from [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHFetchOptions_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHFetchOptions/predicate), I get the correct result back: 1 slow mo video.

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [PHFetchOptions new];
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaSubtype & %d) != 0 || (mediaSubtype & %d) != 0", PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoTimelapse, PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
```

But I'm trying to *exclude* slow mo, rather than select it. However if I negate the filter condition, I get zero results back:

```
options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mediaSubtype & %d) == 0", PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];

<PHFetchResult: 0x1702a6660> count=0
```

Confusingly, the Apple docs list the name of the field as [`mediaSubtypes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHAsset/mediaSubtypes) (with an "s"), while their sample predicate is filtering on `mediaSubtype` (without an "s").

Trying to filter on `mediaSubtypes` produces an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do bit operators on non-numbers'
```

Has anyone been able to make heads or tails of this predicate?

Comment: Plus one. We've had similar problems. No fix yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, let me say about the `s` in `mediaSubtypes` available on `PHAsset` and only Photos team at Apple knows why and how `mediaSubtype` works without an `s`.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) PHAssetMediaType mediaType;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) PHAssetMediaSubtype mediaSubtypes;
```

Now let me try to explain why it doesn't work as expected. Here's how you compare using NS_OPTIONS or any other bitwise operation.

```
PHAsset* asset = // my asset;
if((asset.mediaSubtypes & PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot) == PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot) {
    // This is a screenshot
}
```

Here's how you would compare to see if asset is not a screenshot-

```
PHAsset* asset = // my asset;
if(!((asset.mediaSubtypes & PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot) == PHAssetMediaSubtypePhotoScreenshot)) {
// This is not a screenshot
}
```

Now in your case the predicate should be-

- Fetch all videos with high frame rate

  ```
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((mediaSubtype & %d) == %d)", PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate, PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
  ```
- Fetch all videos without high frame rate

  ```
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!((mediaSubtype & %d) == %d)", PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate, PHAssetMediaSubtypeVideoHighFrameRate];
  ```

This works beautifully in my case. Hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: I would never have figured this out in a million years.

Comment: This is great! FWIW, this appears to be fixed in iOS 13!